# Выдвинуть меню, на чистых XAML триггерах, реально ли?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Допустим у меня есть некое кастомное меню, которое должно появляться с левого края, двигая правый блок *(`Grid`)*, вправо. Сначала решил сделать простую анимацию выезжающего меню меняя его размеры от `0` до `220` *(узнать бы сколько еще ему надо места)*. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня нет кнопки. у меня есть бордюр, в который положена иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я не совсем понимаю как мне сделать так, что бы была проверка на факт что ширина меню равна `0` *(ну или просто запустить анимацию расширения если все еще не свернулось)*.

Т.е. стало примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот теперь я не знаю как мне поступить в таком случае, не использую команды, и `Codebehind`.

Можно ли это реализовать?

P.S. Точнее я не понимаю как мне запускать анимации выдвижения и закрытия меню.

Минимальный класс:

```
public class MenuBordered : Border
{
    public bool IsOpenning
    {
        get { return GetValue<bool>(IsOpenningProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenningProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsOpenning.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenningProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpenning", typeof(bool), typeof(MenuBordered), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private T GetValue<T>(DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        return (T)GetValue(dp);
    }
}
```

Минимальный пример:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:MenuBordered x:Name="MenuBordered" Background="Chocolate" />

        <Border Background="Coral" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Start" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="7,3">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseUp">
                        <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <!--[ Вот тут то я и не понмаю что мне сделать что бы при нажатии хотя бы на данную кнопку без команды выполнить анимацию задвижения, выдвижения ]-->
                        </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Что то я нечего не понял... `решил сделать простую анимацию` - Как сделали? Работает? `нет кнопки. у меня есть бордюр` - и почему это проблема? Не получается клик сделать или...? `была проверка на факт что ширина меню равна 0` - для чего такая проверка? Что бы анимация стартовала исключительно с 0? Так не проще вообще убрать `From`, тогда получите плавную анимацию с текущей ширины. В общем, очень бы помогло понять вопрос более подробное описание с самодостаточным примером.

Comment: Дело в том что  я не понимаю как мне запускать анимации выдвижения и закрытия меню. Как обрабатывать нажатие мышью на бордюр триггерами, дабы запускать анимации.

Comment: Совсем без кода я бы не стал делать, как минимум, надо свойство вроде `IsOpen`. Ну и как вариант попробуйте отрицательный Margin и менять его до 0. Потребуется конвертер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну давай сделаем это. Я для этого написал себе AttachProperty, которое позволяет выдвигать что угодно, с любым интервалом времени, и с любой стороны окна. Вот оно:

```
enum SlideDirection
{
    Left,
    Right,
    Top,
    Bottom
}

class AnimateSlideOutProperty
{
    #region Свойства зависимости

    /// <summary>
    /// Идентифицирует воспроизведение анимации скольжения
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Value",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(AnimateSlideOutProperty),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnValueChanged, OnValueUpdated));

    public static bool GetValue(DependencyObject d) => (bool)d.GetValue(ValueProperty);
    public static void SetValue(DependencyObject d, bool value) => d.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Продолжительность анимации
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DurationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Duration",
    typeof(float),
    typeof(AnimateSlideOutProperty),
    new PropertyMetadata(0.3f));

    public static float GetDuration(DependencyObject d) => (float)d.GetValue(DurationProperty);
    public static void SetDuration(DependencyObject d, float value) => d.SetValue(DurationProperty, value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Направление анимации скольжения
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Direction",
    typeof(SlideDirection),
    typeof(AnimateSlideOutProperty),
    new PropertyMetadata(SlideDirection.Top));

    public static SlideDirection GetDirection(DependencyObject d) => (SlideDirection)d.GetValue(DirectionProperty);
    public static void SetDirection(DependencyObject d, SlideDirection value) => d.SetValue(DirectionProperty, value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Значение смещения скольжения
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Offset",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(AnimateSlideOutProperty),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public static double GetOffset(DependencyObject d) => (double)d.GetValue(OffsetProperty);
    public static void SetOffset(DependencyObject d, double value) => d.SetValue(OffsetProperty, value);

    #endregion

    #region Методы

    private static object OnValueUpdated(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)d;  
        if (!element.IsLoaded)
        {
            RoutedEventHandler onLoaded = null;
            onLoaded = (ss, ee) =>
            {
                var offset = GetOffset(element);
                var direction = GetDirection(element);
                var duration = GetDuration(element);

                // Отписываемся от события элемента Loaded
                element.Loaded -= onLoaded;

                // Проигрываем анимацию
                DoAnimation(element, (bool)value, duration, direction, offset, true);
            };

            // Подписываемся на событие элемента Loaded
            element.Loaded += onLoaded;
        }
        else
        {
            var offset = GetOffset(element);
            var direction = GetDirection(element);
            var duration = GetDuration(element);

            // Проигрываем анимацию
            DoAnimation(element, (bool)value, duration, direction, offset, false);
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Включение анимации затухание или появления в зависимости от значения
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Элемент, на котором происходит анимация</param>
    /// <param name="value">Значение</param>
    public static async void DoAnimation(FrameworkElement element, bool value, float duration, SlideDirection direction, double offset, bool isFirstLoad)
    {
        if(!value)
        {
            // Проигрываем анимацию скольжения возвращения элемента
            await element.SlideBackAsync(isFirstLoad ? 0.0f : duration);
            return;
        }

        // В зависимости от направления анимации скольжения, проигрываем разные анимации
        switch(direction)
        {
            case SlideDirection.Top:
                await element.SlideToTopAsync(isFirstLoad ? 0.0f : duration, offset != 0.0d ? offset : element.ActualHeight);
            break;
            case SlideDirection.Bottom:
                await element.SlideToBottomAsync(isFirstLoad ? 0.0f : duration, offset != 0.0d ? offset : element.ActualHeight);
            break;
            case SlideDirection.Left:
                await element.SlideToLeftAsync(isFirstLoad ? 0.0f : duration, offset != 0.0d ? offset : element.ActualWidth);
            break;
            case SlideDirection.Right:
                await element.SlideToRightAsync(isFirstLoad ? 0.0f : duration, offset != 0.0d ? offset : element.ActualWidth);
            break;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Также я написал несколько extensions методов к `FrameworkElement`:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Анимация скольжения вверх элемента
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Элемент</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность анимации</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task SlideToTopAsync(this FrameworkElement element, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        var storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        // Добавляем анимацию скольжения элемента вверх
        storyBoard.AddSlideToTop(seconds, offset);

        // Запускаем анимацию
        storyBoard.Begin(element);

        // Ждем завершения
        await Task.Delay((int)(seconds * 1000));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Анимация скольжения вниз Вниз
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Элемент</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность анимации</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static async Task SlideToBottomAsync(this FrameworkElement element, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        var storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        // Добавляем анимацию скольжения элемента вверх
        storyBoard.AddSlideToBottom(seconds, offset);

        // Запускаем анимацию
        storyBoard.Begin(element);

        // Ждем завершения
        await Task.Delay((int)(seconds * 1000));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Анимация скольжения влево элемента
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Элемент</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность анимации</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static async Task SlideToLeftAsync(this FrameworkElement element, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        var storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        // Добавляем анимацию скольжения элемента вверх
        storyBoard.AddSlideToLeft(seconds, offset);

        // Запускаем анимацию
        storyBoard.Begin(element);

        // Ждем завершения
        await Task.Delay((int)(seconds * 1000));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Анимация скольжения вправо элемента
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Элемент</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность анимации</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static async Task SlideToRightAsync(this FrameworkElement element, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        var storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        // Добавляем анимацию скольжения элемента вверх
        storyBoard.AddSlideToRight(seconds, offset);

        // Запускаем анимацию
        storyBoard.Begin(element);

        // Ждем завершения
        await Task.Delay((int)(seconds * 1000));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Анимация скольжения назад элемента
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Элемент</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность анимации</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static async Task SlideBackAsync(this FrameworkElement element, float seconds)
    {
        var storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        // Добавляем анимацию скольжения элемента вверх
        storyBoard.AddSlideBack(seconds);

        // Запускаем анимацию
        storyBoard.Begin(element);

        // Ждем завершения
        await Task.Delay((int)(seconds * 1000));
    }
}
```

Ну и несколько extensions методов для `Storyboard` соответственно:

```
public static class StoryboardExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление анимации скольжения вверх
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storyboard">Объект анимаций</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static void AddSlideToTop(this Storyboard storyboard, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        // Создаем объект анимации
        var animation = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)),
            To = new Thickness(0, -offset, 0, offset)
        };

        // Анимация будет происходить над свойством Margin
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));

        // Добавляем анимацию в список анимаций
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление анимации скольжения вниз
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storyboard">Объект анимаций</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static void AddSlideToBottom(this Storyboard storyboard, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        // Создаем объект анимации
        var animation = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)),
            To = new Thickness(0, offset, 0, -offset)
        };

        // Анимация будет происходить над свойством Margin
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));

        // Добавляем анимацию в список анимаций
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление анимации скольжения влево
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storyboard">Объект анимаций</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static void AddSlideToLeft(this Storyboard storyboard, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        // Создаем объект анимации
        var animation = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)),
            To = new Thickness(-offset, 0, offset, 0)
        };

        // Анимация будет происходить над свойством Margin
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));

        // Добавляем анимацию в список анимаций
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление анимации скольжения вправо
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storyboard">Объект анимаций</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Смещение</param>
    public static void AddSlideToRight(this Storyboard storyboard, float seconds, double offset)
    {
        // Создаем объект анимации
        var animation = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)),
            To = new Thickness(offset, 0, -offset, 0)
        };

        // Анимация будет происходить над свойством Margin
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));

        // Добавляем анимацию в список анимаций
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление анимации скольжения возвращения
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storyboard">Объект анимаций</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">Продолжительность</param>
    public static void AddSlideBack(this Storyboard storyboard, float seconds)
    {
        // Создаем объект анимации
        var animation = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)),
            To = new Thickness(0)
        };

        // Анимация будет происходить над свойством Margin
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));

        // Добавляем анимацию в список анимаций
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    }
}
```

Вот и все. Теперь применяем:

```
...
<ToggleButton x:Name="button"/>
<Grid local:AnimateSlideOutProperty.Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName="button"}"
      local:AnimateSlideOutProperty.Direction="Top"
      VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <!-- тут контент -->
</Grid>
...
```

Comment: Хммм, интересная штука. надо будет прочитать про аттачед проперти.